# PHP/MYSQL on/off button, continues to go on off

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm coding an on/off button in php/mysql and have a problem which i seem not able to solve.

The button should send a 1 to the database when its "ON" and a 0 WHEN it's off.

The php/sql

```
if(isset($_POST['postData'])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($db, 
        "UPDATE setting SET post= CASE
                                    WHEN post= 1 THEN 0 
                                    WHEN post= 0 THEN 1
                                    ELSE post END
        WHERE id='" . $userID . "'");
};
```

This snippet works in sql and updates correctly but if the button is 'ON' and still on while it is sended again it will go 'OFF' again and send a 0.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM setting";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

The PHP

```
  <form method="post" action="updateSetting.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="seventy"></div>
        <div class="thirty">
    if($row['post'] == 1){
        echo '      <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="postData" name="postData" />
                    <label for="postData"><span class="bal"></span> AAN     <span class="right">UIT</span>';
} elseif($row['post'] == 0){
    echo '      <input type="checkbox" id="postData" name="postData" />
                    <label for="postData"><span class="bal"></span> AAN      <span class="right">UIT</span>';
} else {} 
 </div>
 <input type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-primary">
 </form>
```

It seems to be stuck on a loop where it turns on and off. I assume it is about the Query but i'm not sure as the Query works correctly as i want it. Please help i seem to be stuck

Comment: your checkboxes have no values.

Comment: plus, it might be something in your unknown SELECT. Might be missing a WHERE clause, who knows.

Comment: I've added the unkown select

Comment: Where are you making a POST request? Also, Is your userId in Update query correct?

Comment: as would the button / form placement etc. It's really hard to troubleshoot this when we don't know exactly how everything is structured.

Comment: @DanglingCruze Yes the userID is correct and the post request is because of the sql being in a seperate php file

Comment: How are you sending the POST request? via AJAX or a simple form submit? Also, you are selecting the settings without any user id in where clause. Are you sending the user id with the POST request for which the settings is getting updated?

Comment: @DanglingCruze I'm sending it with simple form submit, the user id is defined in a database.php and is accesssabel globally

Comment: As you've selected the first row from the `Select * from setting` query. You probably have the wrong user setting listed in the checkbox. Try echoing out the user id for that row to see If it is the same that is defined in the global and getting updated.

Comment: It was the same as it is globally defined and updates correctly! I've found the problem! It was 'faulty' query. by defining the going from 1 to 0 in a new !isset the problem was fixed! Thank you for the help anyways @DanglingCruze